# php problems with memcached

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I am trying to cache some of the most frequently used queries on my site using memcached. The problem is, it keeps returning NULL.

Here's some code;

```
$get_announcements = core::$mem->get('index_announcements');
if ($get_announcements === false) // there's no cache
{
    $get_announcements = $dbl->run("SELECT `id`, `text`, `user_groups`, `type`, `modules`, `can_dismiss` FROM `announcements` ORDER BY `id` DESC")->fetch_all();
    core::$mem->set('index_announcements', $get_announcements, 600);
}
```

So I'm grabbing the key, then checking if it's set, if it's not then grab it from the database and set it.

The problem is, it seems to work for a time, but then eventually just returns NULL when I check it by doing:

```
var_dump(core::$mem->get('index_announcements'));
```

It seems the key is actually set, but it's contents are empty? Is this how expiring works normally in memcached? I'm really confused.

Comment: `core::$mem->set('index_announcements', $get_announcements, 600);`
Well, ... after 600 seconds the key will expire

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't seem to. I just end up with it sticking around giving me NULL. So the code above ends up not working for a cache.

Comment: You are right that IF the key expires it must return FALSE.
Are you sure you connection to memcache server is OK?
Sometimes [it returns NULL if the connection is broken](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4417)

Comment: I think *may* have just found the problem. Since I'm using PDO, when I "fetchAll" it returns an empty array - so my "index_announcements" was getting filled with an empty array, which isn't picked up by checking for false - doh. Adding a check for null seems to work.

Comment: Still...that doesn't explain why it suddenly returns NULL anyway, but at least this way works...